# Convert SQL Server Query to MS Access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2007

Here is my SQL Server Query that needs to be converted to MS Access -

```
declare @StartDateTime datetime, @EndDateTime datetime
set @StartDateTime  = '8/17/2013 19:00:00'
set @EndDateTime = '8/18/2013 23:00:00'

WHILE @StartDateTime <> @EndDateTime
Begin
  SELECT TOP 1 tablename.Field2, tablename.Field3
  FROM tablename
  WHERE tablename.SampleDate >= DateAdd(mi,0,@StartDateTime) And tablename.SampleDate <= DateAdd(mi,9,@StartDateTime)    
  SET @StartDateTime = DateAdd(mi,10,@StartDateTime)
  if @StartDateTime = @EndDateTime
   Break;       
END
```

I appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: What is it you want to accomplish?

Comment: this query gives me the right results in sql server and i want to use MS Access to get the same result. I never worked with  Access before.

Answer (score 2):

That T-SQL script has no direct equivalent in Access. It returns multiple result sets, one for each 10-minute interval between @StartDateTime and @EndDateTime, each containing a single (apparently random) sample from that interval. Access queries only produce one result set (recordset).

If you update your question to explain what you actually want to *do* with those multiple result sets then we might be able to help you more, but for now the answer to

> How can I convert this SQL Server query to an Access query?

is:

You can't.

Comment: Makes sense, totally. What if i use a temp table and add resultant rows to that table, and select from temp table at the end? this would produce just one resultant set !